# How to decide a text box length based on the text size?

Tags: font, font-sizes, textbox, size

If I have a fixed text width, let's say 35 characters, I know the font and font size, Arial Regular 13, how can I calculate the size of the text box required to fit in the text? Is there a formula or thumb-rule for the same?

Answer (score 1):

#### Size it for the worst-case scenario

As you're probably aware, Arial is not a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), so if you want to ensure that your text box can always hold all 35 characters, the best you can do is size your text box for the worst-case scenario: **35 of the widest character in the set**. This way, you'll know it'll be able to show any combinations of narrower characters. The required text box size can then be found through simple trial-and-error.